# CSS conflict font is transparent

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a problem that some text (a Calendar plugin) on my website is transparent, with an ugly shadow border. I think it's a CSS problem in my theme. When I place the calendar widget in my footer, the text is transparent (with a shadow border), when I place the widget on de right section it's ok. I tried to use the F12 button (inspect element), to see where the conflict is, but I can't find it. See below the details. On the website, you can see on the right side the correct text format and on the footer the wrong text format.

CMS: Wordpress 3.8.1
URL: http://www.brug.nu/
Plugin: All-in-One Event Calendar 1.10.9 Standard
Theme: Primo Pro from Cyberchimps 1.0.0.3

Does anyone know if it's really a CSS problem and which section is the cause of the transparent text?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following CSS to your page, after any linked stylesheets in order to override the default styling of the calendar text:

```
#footer-widgets aside, #footer-widgets aside a {
    color: #000000;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Of course, you may want to change the above as you see fit.